# Capture and handle HTTP request error on page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I am seeking a way of using user script to handle HTTP request errors on page, is there a way to detect them such as read what has been posted on the console?

The scenario is the page failed on a GET or POST, now my user script captured it and do something.